# scikit learn. Custom Estimators in multiprocessing pipeline with n_jobs=-1

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I wrote custom transformers and constructed pipeline in scikit learn. Now i'm trying to  tune this pipeline using GridSearchCV. Everything worked fine until I tried to put n_jobs=-1 to speed up the process.

GUI Jupyter notebook did not write about any problems, and only showed that the kernel is busy, but inside of the console there were printed the following error copied several times:
[image: Jupyter notebook consone log]
Drop Fields is the name of one of my custom transformer( don't know whether this is important, but it is the first step of the pipeline). It is defined as follows:

```
class DropFields(FieldsTransformerMixin, Transformer):  
    def __init__(self, fields=None, all_except=False):
        self.fields = fields
        self.all_except = all_except

    def _fit_before(self, data):
        self.fields_ = list(set(data.columns) - set(self.fields)) if self.all_except else list(self.fields)

    def _transform_before(self, data):
        return  data.drop(self.fields_, axis=1)
```

Parents(in notebook defined in above cell):

```
class Transformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    pass

class FieldsTransformerMixin:
    def __init__(self, fields=None):
        self.fields = fields 

    def fit(self, data, y=None):
        self._validate_params()
        self._fit_before(data)
        for field in self.fields:
            self._fit_field(field, data)
        return self

    def transform(self, data):
        data = data.copy()
        data = self._transform_before(data)
        for field in self.fields:
            data = self._transform_field(field, data)
        return data

    def _validate_params(self):
        if self.fields is None:
            raise ValueError('Fields is none.')

    ... empty definitions of _fit_before,_fit_field,
    ... definitions of _transform_before and _transform_field returning default data
```

### The question is:

Am i  need to implement **specific logic** in  Custom estimators for using  them with **n_jobs=-1**,  and if not, then what's the problem here? Why multiprocessing can't find  "DropFields"?

Answer (score 1):

scikit-learn estimators need to support cloning for cross validation to multi-process them with n_jobs=-1. You can see their documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#cloning). base.clone takes your custom estimator class, calls its get_params() function and creates copies by repeatedly calling the class initializer with the same parameters it retrieved from the original class' get_params() method.

Your custom estimator class also has to be "picklable." If your custom estimator class is not defined at the root of your module, that will lead to errors. The estimator class needs to get everything it needs as arguments and run separate from your module.